# How to use the ExecutorService with database pooled connections correctly?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a project where I am reading data from a file, executing some SQL in a data base, and writing data out to the database. One of the file input fields has between 25-50 different parameters (values for attributes of a product) I must query before writing data to the file. This is the slowest part of my process - so I thought it would be good to try to implement this with multiple threads.

I need to run a select statement for every attribute value and create a new value if the value does not already exist. The creation involves simply writing and SQL insert statement into a batch - and the batch will get committed as part of a database transaction after I process all data for a given product.

I have an `AttributeLoader` class that processes all product attributes - including parsing the incoming attribute information, looking up ids for attributes and then looking up ids for values - and creating a new attribute value and id if one does not exist.

I also have a `FindAttrValByIdentifier` class that is the runnable class for retrieving the attribute value if it already exists. My plan is to utilize the `ExecutorService` to run around 20 threads executing the `select` queries - and each thread will be passed a database connection to use in querying the database. When I run this - it seems to process one incoming line and then hangs. So, someplace I seem to have something hung in a wait state. Below is a skeleton of my code. Does anyone see where I derailed? It could be multiple places as I am not a Java Guru - especially when it comes to multiple threads. I tried to cut the code down to just the applicable lines - so let me know if I've cut too much.

```
//my control class (SpeedLoader)opens the connection pool 
public class SpeedLoader {

private static void initializeConnectionPool() throws PropertyVetoException          {
    cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    cpds.setDriverClass( DB_DRIVER ); //loads the jdbc driver            
    cpds.setJdbcUrl( DB_CONNECTION );
    cpds.setUser(DB_USER);                                  
    cpds.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD); 

 // the settings below are optional -- c3p0 can work with defaults
    cpds.setMinPoolSize(5);                                     
    cpds.setAcquireIncrement(5);
    cpds.setMaxPoolSize(25);
    cpds.setMaxStatements(25);
}
public static synchronized Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return cpds.getConnection();
}

class AttributeLoader {     //this class loads attribute data - and is a single instance that is used throughout the complete load process

AttributeLoader(Connection conn, String filePath, String fileTimestamp) throws Exception {
        dbConnection = conn;
        initialize(filePath, fileTimestamp);
}
public static void  processAttributesForPN(String productPN, long productId) throws Exception{

   List<Future<Long>> future=new ArrayList<Future<Long>>();
   List<FindAttrValIdByIdentifier> callList = new ArrayList<FindAttrValIdByIdentifier>();
   for(Map.Entry<Key, Long> entry : attrValIdCache.entrySet()){  // get values for existing keys
        FindAttrValIdByIdentifier getValId = new FindAttrValIdByIdentifier(entry.getKey().attrId, entry.getKey().identifier);
        callList.add(getValId);
   }
    future=executor.invokeAll(callList);

    // process results 
}
private static void initialize(String filePath, String fileTimestamp) throws Exception {
    try {
        attributeDataFileReader =  new FileReader(filePath+"/"+fileTimestamp+".CatentryAttribute.csv");
        attributeBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(attributeDataFileReader);

    //other stuff
    executor  = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

public static void close() throws IOException, SQLException{// close is not called until all file processing completes

    // other stuff
    FindAttrValIdByIdentifier.close();
    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    }


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class FindAttrValIdByIdentifier implements Callable<Long> {

long  attrId;
String identifier;
static Connection pooledConnection;
static PreparedStatement psSelectAttrValId;

public FindAttrValIdByIdentifier(long i, String s) throws SQLException {
    super();
    attrId = i;
    identifier = s;
    pooledConnection = SpeedLoader.getConnection();
    psSelectAttrValId = pooledConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT ATTRVAL_ID FROM ATTRVAL WHERE ATTR_ID=? AND IDENTIFIER=? FOR READ ONLY");
}


public static void close() throws SQLException{
    try {pooledConnection.close();} catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    try {psSelectAttrValId.close();} catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
 }
public Long call()  {
  try  { 
    psSelectAttrValId.setLong(1, attrId);
    psSelectAttrValId.setString(2, identifier);     
    ResultSet rs = psSelectAttrValId.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()){
        return(rs.getLong(1));
    }
//        System.out.println("Thread " + m_myId +  " is finished. ");
    return 0L;
  } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Thread got Exception: AtrrId, Identifier= "+attrId+","+identifier+"  Error: " + e);
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw(new Error("AttrId:"+attrId+ " AttrValIdentifier: "+identifier+   " FindAttrValIdByIdentifier.call() "+e.getMessage()));
  } finally {

  }
```